# Failure to find jar in repository when I build Livy using "mvn clean package"

Tags: maven, livy

I am a newbie of Livy and I build Livy as the official said. The command is as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-livy.git

cd incubator-livy

mvn package
```

Then I get error as follows：

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1 or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved:  Failure to find
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.4.1 in 
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced ->`

I clean the `~/.m2/` and I use `mvn -U clean package`, it failed too. Could anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: What happens if you point your browser to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/1.4.1/maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.1.jar , do you get an error or do you see an JAR file?

Comment: Its there http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/

Comment: @Ferrybig I use my browser to visit the url and download `maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.1.jar`

Comment: @nullpointer I can not understand what you say. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: I use `curl -O https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/1.4.1/maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.1.jar` and also download the jar to my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install python package as follows:

`cloudpickle
requests
requests-kerberos
flake8
flaky
pytest`

It will work